# (itext7) Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document exception when trying to create multiple pdf files using do/while loop

Tags: java, itext7

I have a do/while loop in my Main class so the user can create multiple pdfs without having to close and reopen the program. The Main class sends user input and information to another class that uses itext7 to organize information in to tables and creates the PDF file. The first run works fine with a PDF created, but on the second run I receive the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to 
other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:212)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:202)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:109)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:204)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:109)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:204)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:109)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.writeToBody(PdfWriter.java:324)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.flushObject(PdfWriter.java:214)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushObject(PdfDocument.java:1980)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:187)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:153)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObjectWrapper.flush(PdfObjectWrapper.java:94)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:546)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:474)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:955)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:117)
    at hemolysis_V3.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:196)
    at hemolysis_V3.Collector.switcher(Collector.java:64)
    at hemolysis_V3.Main.main(Main.java:110)
```

a new PDF file is still created, but acrobat says the file is damaged and cannot be repaired.

This is what I currently have. The exception points to the document.close(), but I don't understand why. I thought that a new document object would be created each time this class is called by the main, but that doesn't seem to be the case. To get around that I created an array of Document objects so that each loop would use a different Document, but that didn't work either. FileNamer() is working properly because a new PDF file is still created, but acrobat says the file is damaged and cannot be repaired.

```
//static variable
private static PdfWriter PdfWriter;

private static PdfDocument pdfDocument;
private static Document document;
private static File file;
private static String fileName;    
// class is called by the main to create the PDF
public static void format() throws IOException{
String fileName = FileNamer(); // creates a new filename to prevent overwriting other files
String location = ("C:\\Users");
file = new File(location, fileName);
PdfWriter = new PdfWriter(file);
pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(PdfWriter);
Document doc0 = new Document (pdfDocument);
    Document doc1 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc2 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc3 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc4 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc5 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc6 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc7 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc8 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document doc9 = new Document (pdfDocument);
Document[] ListOfDocs= {doc0, doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5, doc6, doc7, doc8, doc9};

//statements

ListOfDocs[loops].close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a method to set the fonts for each iteration of the loop.

```
//static variables
private static PdfWriter PdfWriter;
    private static PdfDocument pdfDocument;
    private static Document document;
    private static File file;
    private static String fileName = FileNamer();

     public static void setFormatter() throws IOException {
        PdfFont symbol = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.SYMBOL);
        PdfFont courier = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);
        Formatter.small = new Style().setFont(courier).setFontSize(fontSizeSmol);
        Formatter.mid = new Style().setFont(courier).setFontSize(fontSizeMid);
        Formatter.large = new Style().setFont(courier).setFontSize(fontSizeLarge);
        Formatter.lambda = new Style().setFont(symbol);
    }
public static void format(String[] GDP, List<List<List<String>>> records, String[] results, int runs, int loops) throws IOException {
        setFormatter();
        
        file = new File(location, fileName);
        PdfWriter = new PdfWriter(file);
        pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(PdfWriter);
        document = new Document(pdfDocument);

//statements

document.close();
```